# vb.net making threads in a loop possible?

Tags: vb.net, multithreading

I have the following script which creates 2 threads as you can see.The thing is I would like this code to be tidy-er and the thread making better (such as a loop) but I haven't been able to manage to create it.

Now i dim thread1 and thread 2 and have separate functions for both.
I am really new to vb.net so please dont shoot be down.

How would I make a public MaxThreads as integer = 2 (or whatever)
and then be able to 
for i as 1 to MaxThreads
' what now is in function startthread1 
next

```
Public Class UnCheckedItemReader
    Public ForceStop As Boolean = False ' to force shutdown in case the application is Closed
    Public UnCheckedItems As Integer ' to check and report
    Public QueueList As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) ' this list will contain the addressbook ID and the number of the thread holding it
    Public QueueProcessed As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) ' this will aloow us to update the Clientlistview

    Private ds As New DataSet
    Private da As SqlCeDataAdapter = New SqlCeDataAdapter()
    Private connection As New ConnectionClass
    Private table As String = "uncheckItems"

    'threads section - we have 2 threads
    Dim Thread1 As Threading.Thread
    Dim Thread2 As Threading.Thread

    Public Sub Controller()

        Do While ForceStop = False
            If QueueList.Count < 1 Then
                GetDatabaseSqlClientListUnCheckedItems()
                PopulateQueueList()
                StartThreads()
            End If
            Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000)
            Console.WriteLine("New Round")
        Loop


    End Sub



    Private Sub StartThreads()
        StartThread1()
        StartThread2()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartThread1()
        Dim DS As New RelianProcess
        DS.id = 5
        DS.ThreadId = 1
        DS.QueueList = QueueList

        AddHandler DS.ShowError, AddressOf ShowErrorThread1
        AddHandler DS.Stopit, AddressOf StopThread1
        Thread1 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DS.StartTimer)
        Thread1.IsBackground = True

        Try
            Thread1.Start()
        Catch e As ThreadStateException
            Console.WriteLine("Caught: {0}", e.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Caught: {0}", ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Sub StartThread2()
        Dim DS As New RelianProcess
        DS.id = 5
        DS.ThreadId = 2
        DS.QueueList = QueueList

        AddHandler DS.ShowError, AddressOf ShowErrorThread1
        AddHandler DS.Stopit, AddressOf StopThread1
        Thread2 = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DS.StartTimer)
        Thread2.IsBackground = True

        Try
            Thread2.Start()
        Catch e As ThreadStateException
            Console.WriteLine("Caught: {0}", e.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("Caught: {0}", ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub




    Private Sub ShowErrorThread1(ByVal e As Exception, ByVal id As Integer)
        Console.Write(e.ToString)
        QueueList.Remove(id)

        Console.Write(vbCrLf + "Removed from Mother queuelist " + CStr(id))
        QueueProcessed.Add(id, CInt(GetCurrentUnixTimestamp()))
        Console.Write(vbCrLf + "Added to processed list " + CStr(id))
    End Sub

    Private Sub ShowErrorThread2(ByVal e As Exception, ByVal id As Integer)
        Console.Write(e.ToString)
        QueueList.Remove(id)

        Console.Write(vbCrLf + "Removed from Mother queuelist " + CStr(id))
        QueueProcessed.Add(id, CInt(GetCurrentUnixTimestamp()))
        Console.Write(vbCrLf + "Added to processed list " + CStr(id))
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopThread1()
        Thread1.Abort()
    End Sub

    Private Sub StopThread2()
        Thread2.Abort()
    End Sub


    Private Sub PopulateQueueList()
        Dim i As Integer = 1
        If ds.Tables(table).Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For Each irow As DataRow In ds.Tables(table).Rows
                Try
                    If QueueList.ContainsKey(CInt(irow(0))) = False Then
                        i = i + 1
                        If i = 3 Then 
                            i = 1
                        End If

                        QueueList.Add(CInt(irow(0)), i)
                        Console.WriteLine(ControlChars.NewLine + "Added item {0} to thread {1}", irow(0), i)

                    End If
                Catch e As Exception
                    Console.WriteLine(ControlChars.NewLine + "Exception Raised. The following error occured : {0}", e.Message)
                End Try
            Next
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Suggestions: stop catching exceptions, or if you must, at least output ex.ToString(), not ex.Message, and `Console.WriteLine` doesn't help much in a WinForms application. Also, look into the Task class.

Comment: Hard to be constructive, this is not good code.  Use BackgroundWorker instead.  Educate yourself with books like Joe Duffy's "Concurrent Programming on Windows".  Study the Task class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of declaring each thread individually, use a Collection of Threads. Something along these lines:

```
    Dim m_threads As New List(Of Threading.Thread)
Dim m_maxThreads As Int32 = 5

Private Sub StartAllThreads()


    For pos As Int32 = 1 To m_maxThreads
        StartThread(pos)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub StartThread(p_threadID As Int32)
    Dim tempThread As Threading.Thread
    Dim DS As New RelianProcess


    DS.id = 5
    DS.ThreadId = p_threadID
    DS.QueueList = QueueList

    tempThread = New System.Threading.Thread(AddressOf DS.StartTimer)
    m_threads.Add(tempThread)

    AddHandler DS.ShowError, AddressOf ShowErrorThread1
    AddHandler DS.Stopit, AddressOf StopThread1
    tempThread.IsBackground = True

    Try
        tempThread.Start()
    Catch e As ThreadStateException
        Console.WriteLine("Caught: {0}", e.Message)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Caught: {0}", ex.Message)
    End Try

End Sub
```